# Why cannot add String to type to List<?>?

Tags: java, generics

The error:

```
The method add(capture#1-of ?) in the type List<capture#1-of ?> is not 
applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Code:

```
List<?> to = new ArrayList<Object>();
to.add(new String("here"));
```

Since `List<?>` is a generic type List and therefore can be of any type, then why it is not accepting String in add method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `List<?>` is a list of some type, which is unknown. So you can't add anything to it except null without breaking the type-safety of the list:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> unknownTypeList = intList;
unknownTypeList.add("hello"); // doesn't compile, now you should see why
```

Answer (score 7):

> should a String not be acceptable ?

No. `<?>` means the type is unknown and the compiler cannot be sure that any type is acceptable to add (this include String)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a lower bound:

```
List<? super Object> to = new ArrayList<Object>();
to.add(new String("here")); // This compiles
```

Now the compiler is sure that the list can contain any Object

Answer (score 1):

According to [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html), `the question mark (?), called the wildcard, represents an unknown type` and not a generic type, since its an `unknown` type the compiler cannot accept `String` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider any list defined using wildcards to be *read only*. Still, there are some non-read operations that you can do.

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html):

- You can add null.
- You can invoke clear.
- You can get the iterator and invoke remove.
- You can capture the wildcard and write elements that you've read from the list.