# capture of ? extends BasePage do not match to the generic

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I try to create storage for my PageFactory in the follow way:

```java
    private static Map<Class<? extends BasePage>, ? extends BasePage> pageStore = new HashMap<>();
    
    @SneakyThrows
    public <T extends BasePage> T getPage(Class<T> pageClazz) {
        T t = pageClazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        pageStore.put(pageClazz, t);//   <----   here is compilation error
        return null;
    }
```

So, from the part of code you can understand where I have the compilation error, although both `?` and `T` extended from the `BasePage`:

```
Required type: capture of ? extends BasePage do not math to the generic
Provided: T
```

Do I have to change type from `<? extend BasePage>` to the `BasePage` or I can save current logic and cast my object in the another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `pageStore` HashMap to use `BasePage` in the value and add to the map by using inheritance relationship because any divided class will have `BasePage` parent

```java
private static Map<Class<? extends BasePage>, BasePage> pageStore = new HashMap<>();

public <T extends BasePage> T getPage(Class<T> pageClazz) throws Exception {
    T t = pageClazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    pageStore.put(pageClazz, t);
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You get this because you most likely have a common misconception of what the meaning of wildcards is in Java generics.

The type `? extends BasePage` for the values of the map does **not** mean that you can put objects of different types that extend `BasePage` as values in this map.

It means: the type of the values in this map is a *specific, but unknown* type that extends `BasePage`.

You cannot put any values into such a map, because the type that the values are supposed to have, is unknown. When you try to put a value in such a map, there is not enough information for the compiler to check that the value you are adding has the correct type, because the compiler doesn't know what the specific type is that the `?` stands for.

It's exactly the same as why you [cannot add anything to a `List<?>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633357/why-cannot-add-string-to-type-to-list).

If you need to store objects of different types that are all subtypes of `BasePage`, then the right solution is indeed to use `BasePage` instead of `? extends BasePage` for the type of the values of the map.

Comment: The key is more of a problem. It is declared as `Class<? extends BasePage>` - and it is impossible to say "any `Class<? extends BasePage>`" and not "some specific `Class<T>`", where `T extends BasePage`".

Comment: “*You cannot put any values into such a map*” except `null`. Or, when you pass the map to a generic method which captures the wildcard into a new type variable, you can retrieve values from the map and pass them back into the map, e.g. under a different key. Besides that, it’s correct, you can not pass new non-null values into the map when you only have a reference with a wildcard type.